# Tune My Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a JavaScript global Array, which I'm using in multiple functions. I heard that using global variables will give some performance headache. So, can anyone suggest me how I can avoid using global variable in this case?

```
var tpaArray = new Array();
```

In multiple functions, I am using and popping value from it.

[Note] In my code I am actually using multiple global variable and arrays

Comment: The issue isn't that globals cause performance headaches; they don't. It's that they make for complicated, messy code. That said, there is no way for anyone to tell what you could do differently, because you didn't provide any real code; you just gave us a variable declaration.

Comment: By global it means you are declaring a variable inside the `window` scope: `window.tpaArray = []` is a global variable.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: The OP's variable will be global if that declaration is outside of any function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - So it is inside the `window` scope.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: It is inside global scope. On browsers, the global object has a property, `window`, that it uses to refer to itself. This is a peculiarity of the browser environment. But my point was that you seemed to be correcting the OP about what a global variable is, but the OP's code creates one (provided the declaration is at global scope).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Oh, `window.tpaArray` is just an example... I didn't mean to correct him or something.

Comment: @EdCottrell : my question was taken wrongly here, whenever and watever article i read about js performance issue, they tell dont declare Global variables but if you have no other option , what i can do ? i think this question dont deserve -ve points.

Comment: It's not a performance issue. If you have read articles that say the problem is performance, they are wrong. It's a debugging/coding/maintenance issue. The solution is to avoid global variables; pass the data you need to functions or object methods, rather than making it global. But your question does not give any information about what you are doing with `tpaArray`, so no one can help you with your specific concern.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are not a performance problem. The problem with globals is that the global namespace is already very, very crowded, and so dumping your symbols there leads to the possibility of conflicting with something else.

It's almost always possible to avoid having globals. The usual way is to wrap all of your code in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    // Your code here
})();
```

Then you can have nested functions inside that function, and "globals" within that function that they all share.

```
(function() {
    var someVar;

    function foo() {
        // You can use `someVar` here
    }

    function bar() {
        // And also here
    }

    foo();
})();
```

That said, it's best to avoid having lots of shared variables or near globals, as it makes for writing functions with side-effects, which can be difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of variables, you can put them all into an object and pass this as an argument to each function. Then instead of accessing `tpaArray`, you'd access `data.tpaArray`, where `data` is the name of the argument.